# pass max_execution_time through mysql engine

Tags: mysql, clickhouse

Its error when I send a query to mysql from clickhouse server.
Mysql can't understand query like

```
SELECT /*+ MAX_EXECUTION_TIME(1000) */ column1, column2 
from mysql_tables.table1
```

from clickhouse through a table created with the mysql engine.

How to correctly enter the MAX_EXECUTION_TIME() constraint? to the mysql engine when creating a table like

```
    CREATE TABLE mysql_tables.table1
    (
        `id` Int32,
        `status` Int32
    )
    ENGINE = MySQL('host',
     'db',
     'table1',
     'user',
     'password',
)
SETTINGS [MAX_EXECUTION_TIME=1000]
```

or to the query itself?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you can't pass comment to MySQL

According to

https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/engines/table-engines/integrations/mysql/#read-write-timeout

you can set up SETTINGS read_write_timeout=XXX

Unfortunately, this is not max execution time, and query still run on MySQL side

but if you will use ProxySQL, and setup default_query_timeout
https://proxysql.com/documentation/global-variables/mysql-variables/
it could work